# funcion yield - cuadrados de los digitos

Tags: python

alguien sabría como realizar una funcion generadora de los cuadrados del 1 al 10 con YIELD.
Sé que en este foro no se resuelven preguntas sin código pero fue una pregunta que me salió en el primer examen y querría aprender a hacerla para la segunda oportunidad.
Gracias

Comment: `def f():
    for i in range(1,11):
        yield i*i`

Comment: no es que no te ayudemos si no muestras código, la cosa es mostrar que haz intentado, igual Candid Moe ya te lo respondio

Comment: Cerraron la pregunta con la tarea hecha¿cuál es el objetivo?

Comment: Te creo, pero puede que algunos mientan diciendo lo que vos dijiste para que les resolvamos la tarea. Primero intenta resolver ese ejercicio por tu cuenta, luego podremos ayudarte c:

Comment: Además, StackOverflow no es un foro.

Comment: @tincopasan la pregunta carece de un ejemplo minimo y verificable. Como dice el motivo de cierre, faltan detalles a la pregunta. Además, como dije dos comentarios más arriba, existe la posibilidad de que esté mintiendo. Y por ultimo, si nosotros le contestamos así nomas, no podrá aprender a hacer dicho código por su cuenta. Al menos estas son las razones por las que yo hubiera votado por el cierre de la pregunta.

Comment: @DanteS. "Y por ultimo, si nosotros le contestamos así nomas, no podrá aprender a hacer dicho código por su cuenta",¿leíste el primer comentario? es la respuesta completa. entonces cierran la pregunta , que me parece bien, ¿pero permiten la respuesta solapada en comentario? Y después a otros le crítican y puntuan negativo.

Comment: @tincopasan tienes razon... Perdón por decirlo, pero para mi dar una respuesta disfrazada de comentario es tan perjudicial para el OP como dar una respuesta normal a su pregunta.